# Rename form field name using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can I rename a field of my form using Javascript? Like changing:

```
<input type="text" name="chicken" id="chicken"/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="horse" id="horse"/>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read any documents on DOM-manipulation?

Comment: How about removing and adding new element to the dom object.

Answer (score 12):

Of course it is possible:

```
var field = document.getElementById("chicken");
field.id = "horse";  // using element properties
field.setAttribute("name", "horse");  // using .setAttribute() method
```

Comment: i don't think `.id` renames the object. apparently it changes the id.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the `name` attribute, but in my opinion, you shouldn't change the `id`.

You can use :

```
document.getElementById("chicken").setAttribute('name', 'horse');
```

**Edit**

The following statement is purely subjective, and might not have some room on SO.

From [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id) :

> The id attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> - As a style sheet selector.
> - As a target anchor for hypertext links.
> - **As a means to reference a particular element from a script.**
> - As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
> - For general purpose processing by user agents (e.g. for identifying    fields when extracting data from HTML pages into a database,
>     translating HTML documents into other formats, etc.)

As I see it, the ID is an unique identifier which is really useful to retrieve an element from a script (among other things), and I personally want to be able to retrieve this single element with the same selector whatever manipulation it endures during runtime. So, I won't change it.

**Example** : if I transform a *chicken* into a *horse*, I keep in mind that it used to be a *chicken* before, and I'd rather remember it as a mutant which I'll select with `$('#chicken[name=horse]')`, and fake it as an *horse* using others CSS selectors.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to change the `id` of an element.

Comment: You have a typo in the name of `.setAttribute()` method.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it possible to change any data at runtime using js :)

```
var elementToRename = document.getElementById("chicken");
elementToRename.id = "horse"; 
elementToRename.setAttribute("name","horse"); = "horse";
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have access to the element object (i.e. with `getElementById`) you can just change its `name` property:

```
el.name = 'horse';
```

The attribute will mirror the value of the property.

Answer (score -1):

how to rename a tab in JavaScript. Below is the code.

```js
var i=parseInt(1);
        var clickid;
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demoTabs").tabs();
        $(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      // $(this).tabs("show");
    })
    .on("click", ".close", function () {
     var w_demo=$('#demoTabs').outerWidth();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#demoTabs").width((w_demo-105)+"px");
 });
    $('.add-tab').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var html="<li class=\"tabs\" id="+i+"><a href=\"#\">New Tab</a><span class=\"close\">x</span></li>";
        $(this).closest('li').before(html);
  var w=$("#demoTabs").outerWidth(); 
        var w=w+95;
        document.getElementById('demoTabs').style.width=w+"px";
        i=i+1;
 });
    if (document.getElementById('demoTabs').addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById('demoTabs').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            $("#rmenu").toggleClass("hide");
            $("#rmenu").css(
              {
                position: "absolute",
                top: e.pageY,
                left: e.pageX
              }
            );
            e.preventDefault();
            clickid=$(this).id;
            prompt(this+" "+clickid);
     }, false);
}

// this is from another SO post...  
$(document).bind("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("rmenu").className = "hide";
});
$("#refresh").click(function(){
    location.reload();
})
$("#rename").click(function(e){
var reply=prompt("type in a name for tab");
if(reply!=null && reply.trim().length>0)
{
     // $(e.target).prev("tabs").text(reply);
       // prompt(clickid);
      document.getElementByClass("").innerHTML=reply;
}
});
     });
```

```css
   #body{
  height:22.8px;
  width:32.4px;
}
#demoTabs{ 
 width:90px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.nav-tabs > li > span {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 8px;
    color: red;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}

#rmenu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#rmenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
#rmenu li{
    list-style: none; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    padding-right: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<body style="position:relative">
    <div id="demoTabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#" class="add-tab">+Add</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class="tab-content">
    </div>
    <div class="hide" id="rmenu">
        <ul>
            <li id="refresh">Refresh</li>
            <li id="rename">Rename</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```